# Error "AddressOf expression cannot be converted to Integer because integer is not delegate type"

Tags: vb.net

I have a small project that I converted from VBA to VB.NET. I keep getting this code *"AddressOf expression cannot be converted to Integer because integer is not delegate type"*:

```
Module Module1
Declare Sub RegisterReceive Lib "apple.dll" (ByVal Procedure As Integer)
Sub CallBack(ByVal Procedure As Integer)
    /// Call
End Sub
```

The error happens on this line:

```
RegisterReceive(AddressOf Module1.CallBack)
```

Comment: Is this how the original VBA code looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Try (ByVal Procedure As **IntPtr**). IntPtr is used for addressing memory.

Comment: I tried. Same error. I've always hated pointers.

Comment: Make CallBack Public, if you're calling it from outside. Also the module should be declared Public.

Answer (score -1):

I finally solved it myself:

```
<DllImport("apple.dll")>
Public Shared Function RegisterReceive(ByVal CallbackAddr As AlertManCallbackDel)
    As Long

End Function

Public Delegate Sub AlertManCallbackDel(ByVal data As IntPtr)
```